# How to calculate Total Time in Java Vaadin TimeFiled, i.e seperate drop down for Hours and Seconds (HH:MM)?

Tags: java, vaadin, timefield

```
if (tfTimeIn.getValue() != null && tfTimeOut.getValue() != null) {
            Long min1 = tfTimeOut.getMinutesValue();
            Long min2 = tfTimeIn.getMinutesValue();
            Long hr1 = tfTimeOut.getHoursValue();
            Long hr2 = tfTimeIn.getHoursValue();
       // Here I need the calculations
            String hrsTotalString = hrsTotal.toString();
            String minTotalString = minTotal.toString();
            tfTotalTime.setValue(hrsTotalString + ":" + minTotalString);
```

}

This is the code. I want to calculate the total time from the separate drop down boxes.

Comment: What do you mean with "total time"? Is your question title correct (minutes instead of seconds)? What should the result be? String? Long? Would be useful when you post your Vaadin code.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * Total time calculation.
 */
private void getTotalHours() {
    try {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (tfTimeIn.getValue() != null && tfTimeOut.getValue() != null) {
            Long min1 = tfTimeOut.getMinutesValue();
            Long min2 = tfTimeIn.getMinutesValue();
            Long hr1 = tfTimeOut.getHoursValue();
            Long hr2 = tfTimeIn.getHoursValue();
            Long hrsTotal = new Long("0");
            Long minTotal = new Long("0");
            if ((hr2 - hr1) == 1) {
                hrsTotal = (long) 1;
                if (min1 != 0 && min2 == 0) {
                    minTotal = (long) 60 - min1;
                } else if (min1 == 0 && min2 != 0) {
                    minTotal = min2;
                } else if (min1 != 0 && min2 != 0) {
                    minTotal = min2;
                    Long minOne = (long) 60 - min1;
                    Long minTwo = min2;
                    minTotal = minOne + minTwo;
                }
                if (minTotal >= 60) {
                    hrsTotal++;
                    minTotal = minTotal % 60;
                }
            } else if ((hr2 - hr1) > 0) {
                hrsTotal = (hr2 - hr1);
                if (min1 != 0 && min2 == 0) {
                    minTotal = (long) 60 - min1;
                } else if (min1 == 0 && min2 != 0) {
                    minTotal = min2;
                } else if (min1 != 0 && min2 != 0) {
                    minTotal = min2;
                    Long minOne = (long) 60 - min1;
                    Long minTwo = min2;
                    minTotal = minOne + minTwo;
                }
                if (minTotal >= 60) {
                    minTotal = minTotal % 60;
                }
            } else if ((hr2 - hr1) == 0) {
                if (min1 != 0 || min2 != 0) {
                    if (min2 > min1) {
                        hrsTotal = (long) 0;
                        minTotal = min2 - min1;
                    } else {
                        Notification.show("Enter A Valid Time");
                        tfTotalTime.setValue("00.00");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Notification.show("Enter A Valid Time");
                tfTotalTime.setValue("00.00");
            }
            String hrsTotalString = hrsTotal.toString();
            String minTotalString = minTotal.toString();
            if (hrsTotalString.trim().length() == 1) {
                hrsTotalString = "0" + hrsTotalString;
            }
            if (minTotalString.trim().length() == 1) {
                minTotalString = "0" + minTotalString;
            }
            tfTotalTime.setValue(hrsTotalString + ":" + minTotalString);
        } else {
            tfTotalTime.setValue("00.00");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks very complicated. I am sure there is a cleaner solution. And btw: I hope you don't use Exception.printStackTrace in production environment. Additionally, the catch of generic "Exception" looks like a code smell.